I am using android intent in flutter, and then want the app to go back to my app how to do it?
I have a project.
This project is need to have a feature that, when we clicked a button
the button will have a timer start, and then will go to another app. I have successfully done that, but the problem is. When the timer come off the another app should be back to my flutter app. I need help with this problem
Thank You.
This is my main_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:wartel_lapas/core/widget/ButtonCustom.dart';
import 'package:wartel_lapas/core/widget/PageCustom.dart';
import 'package:wartel_lapas/pages/token_input_page.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageCustom(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 130,
          right: 18,
          left: 18,
        ),
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/deltakode.png',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Text(
            'Selamat datang!',
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.plusJakartaSans(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Text(
            'Di Aplikasi Wartel Lapas Silahkan \nKlik Tombol di Bawah Ini Untuk \nMemulai',
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.plusJakartaSans(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 210,
          ),
          ButtonCustom(
            placeholder: 'Mulai!',
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const TokenInputPage(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


This is my token_input_dart.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:wartel_lapas/core/widget/ButtonCustom.dart';
import 'package:wartel_lapas/core/widget/PageCustom.dart';
import 'package:wartel_lapas/pages/phone_input_page.dart';

class TokenInputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TokenInputPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TokenInputPage> createState() => _TokenInputPageState();
}

class _TokenInputPageState extends State<TokenInputPage> {
  final _token = TextEditingController();
  int timeLeft = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageCustom(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 130, right: 16, left: 16),
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/deltakode.png',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Text(
            'Masukan Voucher Anda!',
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.plusJakartaSans(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _token,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Masukan Voucher',
                alignLabelWithHint: true,
                labelStyle: GoogleFonts.plusJakartaSans(fontSize: 16)),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ButtonCustom(
            placeholder: 'Masuk',
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => PhoneInputPage(
                    timeLeft: timeLeft,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


And this is my phone_input_page.dart
import 'dart:async';
// import 'package:android_intent/android_intent.dart';
import 'package:android_intent_plus/android_intent.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:wartel_lapas/core/widget/ButtonCustom.dart';
import 'package:wartel_lapas/core/widget/PageCustom.dart';

class PhoneInputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhoneInputPage({super.key, this.timeLeft});

  final timeLeft; // Ensure timeLeft is passed as an integer (in seconds)

  @override
  State<PhoneInputPage> createState() => _PhoneInputPageState();
}

class _PhoneInputPageState extends State<PhoneInputPage> {
  final _phoneController = TextEditingController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  int? balanceAmount;
  String? transactionId;
  Timer? _timer;
  late int _remainingTime; // Countdown timer value

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _phoneController.dispose();
    _timer?.cancel();
    _closeVideoCall();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _startCountdown() {
    _remainingTime = widget.timeLeft; // Initialize with the provided time
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (_remainingTime > 0) {
          _remainingTime--;
        } else {
          _timer?.cancel();
          _closeVideoCall();
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void _closeVideoCall() async {
    print('Waktu Abis');
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text('Panggilan telah diakhiri.')),
    );
    // Bring the app back to the foreground
    // const intent = AndroidIntent(
    //   action: 'action_view',
    //   data: 'package:com.example.wartel_lapas',
    //   package: 'com.example.wartel_lapas',
    // );
    // await intent.launch();
    print('Balik');
  }

  String normalizePhoneNumber(String phone) {
    phone = phone.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\D'), '');
    if (phone.startsWith('0')) {
      phone = '62${phone.substring(1)}';
    }
    if (!phone.startsWith('62')) {
      return ''; // Invalid format
    }
    return phone;
  }

  void _startVideoCall() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    String normalizedPhone = normalizePhoneNumber(_phoneController.text);

    if (normalizedPhone.isEmpty) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Kode negara tidak ada atau salah.')),
      );
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      return;
    }

    _startCountdown();

    final intent = AndroidIntent(
      action: 'action_view',
      data: 'https://wa.me/$normalizedPhone',
      package: 'com.whatsapp',
    );
    await intent.launch();

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageCustom(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 130,
          right: 18,
          left: 18,
        ),
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/deltakode.png',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Text(
            'Masukan Nomor Telepon Yang Dituju!',
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: GoogleFonts.plusJakartaSans(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Text(
            _timer == null
                ? 'Waktu Anda Tersedia: ${widget.timeLeft.toString()} detik'
                : 'Waktu Anda Sisa: $_remainingTime detik',
            style: GoogleFonts.plusJakartaSans(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _phoneController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Nomor Telepon',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ButtonCustom(
            onPressed: isLoading ? null : _startVideoCall,
            placeholder:
                isLoading ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : 'Mulai Chat',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

My package that im using is
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
google_fonts: ^6.2.1
android_intent_plus: ^5.2.0
How to get the second app back to my flutter app
Thank you

Just to understand, you want to automatically switch back to the first application after the button is clicked and the user moved to the second application?

No, when the button is clicked it automatically start a timer, and then navigate to the other app. And when the timer off the second app should navigate back to the first app. That is the thing i need help to solved the problem:)
